# How to find the right indexes for several joined tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following query. the main tables are `company_reports` and `project_con_messages` with 770,000 and 1,040,000 records respectively.
When I run this query it takes about 20 seconds and when I remove the last table `company_par_user_settings` it takes less than 0.5 seconds.
`company_par_user_settings` (short name: pus) has about 200,000 records and is meant to show user settings for each `company_partner`. on `company_par_user_settings` table we have composite unique index key on `partner_id` and `user_id` fields. I also removed the index and replaced with simple indexes on `partner_id` and `user_id` but at the end, it didn't make any big difference in running time.

```
SELECT * 

FROM company_reports rep 
LEFT JOIN system_users usr ON rep.user_id=usr.id 
LEFT JOIN company_rep_subjects sbj ON rep.subject_id=sbj.id 
INNER JOIN company_partners par ON rep.partner_id=par.id 
LEFT JOIN project_con_messages mes ON rep.message_id=mes.id 
LEFT JOIN company_par_user_settings pus ON par.id=pus.partner_id AND 1=pus.user_id

WHERE 1=1 
ORDER BY rep.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Here below I added the explain on the above query:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id   | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              | 
| 1    | SIMPLE      | rep   | NULL       | ALL    | partner_id    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                          | 772236 | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
| 1    | SIMPLE      | par   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | portal_ebrahim.rep.partner_id | 1      | 100.00   | NULL                                               |
| 1    | SIMPLE      | usr   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 2       | portal_ebrahim.rep.user_id    | 1      | 100.00   | Using where                                        |
| 1    | SIMPLE      | sbj   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 2       | portal_ebrahim.rep.subject_id | 1      | 100.00   | NULL                                               |
| 1    | SIMPLE      | mes   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | portal_ebrahim.rep.message_id | 1      | 100.00   | NULL                                               |
| 1    | SIMPLE      | pus   | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                          | 191643 | 100.00   | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I appreciate if someone help me on the right indexes or any other solutions that make the query run faster.

Edit:

Here is the show table for `company_par_user_settings`

```
CREATE TABLE `company_par_user_settings` (
 `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `partner_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `user_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `access` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-Not specified',
 `access_category` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `notify` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `stars` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `partner_id` (`partner_id`,`user_id`),
 KEY `stars` (`stars`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=198729 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci
```

Comment: Can you add the table definition (the output of `show create table company_par_user_settings`) as well as the datatype for par.id/rep.partner_id?

Comment: @Solarflare All tables use MyISAM storage engine.
both **par.id** and **rep.partner_id** are mediumint(8)
I added show create table for `company_par_user_settings` in my main post

Comment: @Solarflare it is surprising that I have the same database on another computer and when I use the same query, I receive a different EXPLAIN result. I compared the two database including table designs, indexes and storage engines. All are the same but the output still differs.